# can someone help me to prove rank(P A) = rank(A).?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]
[image]

is that correct and we should use the hint but how we use it correctly??
[image]

Comment: Did you read the hint?

Comment: I would think that using the fact that row space of $BA$ is a subspace of the rowspace of $A$ - together with the fact that $P$ has an inverse - would be simpler than going via row echelon forms, but to each their own. Mind you, the hint is a nice way, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the notation kernel(A) somewhat better than null(A), The kernel of a matrix A is 
 the set of non-zero vectors x, such that Ax = 0.

Now, we have

$PAx = 0$ if and only if $P^{-1}PAx = Ax = 0$

So, PA and A have the same kernel. Since PA and A also have the same size, they
 must have the same rank beacuse of rank(A) = n - dim(kernel(A)) , if A is a 
 mxn - matrix.

Comment: what about if we have ) If P is an invertible n × n matrix and A is any m × n matrix, prove
rank(AP) = rank(A).